# HTACCESS file is not working on localhost wamp server

Tags: php, string, .htaccess, url, indexing

I am trying to use the code on HTACCESS on my wamp localhost and there is no action. I am not sure wheter the wamp issue or the code.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /con.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: What URL are you requesting? `.htaccess` files are not "enabled" by default. You need to set the appropriate `AllowOverride` directive in the server config / virtual host (and restart Apache).

Comment: con.php this is the url I am using as main

Comment: How should I set AllowOverride in wampserver?

Comment: what is the error you're getting? they should be enabled by default in wamp. are you talking about subdir or the root level?

Comment: "con.php this is the url" - But what is the URL you are requesting? If you are requesting `/con.php` then the rule you posted should not be doing anything. Are you requesting `example.com/` (ie. the homepage) or `example.com/foo` (some internal "page")? Have you tested both? Your rule only processes the later.

Comment: The issue is my code working fine on live server. But showing error on wampserver

Comment: So, you are presumably requesting a non-root URL? (The code you have posted is "unlikely" to work for the _homepage_, ie root directory - on live server or locally.) Have you checked whether `.htaccess` overrides are enabled? Put some "garbage" at the top of the file; do you get an error?

Comment: Yes I do get an Internal Server Error while adding some text on HTACESS

Comment: What about the other questions asked above... what URL are you requesting?? What is happening exactly? What do you mean by "no action"?? Something must be happening, it can't literally be _nothing_. What response are you seeing? 404 Not Found? 403? An error? Something else? "con.php this is the url I am using as main" - This doesn't make sense as you shouldn't be requesting `con.php` (URL) to begin with. (Honestly, it's like trying to get blood from a stone!?)

Comment: <?php
 function base(){
  echo str_replace("index.php","",$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
 }

 $url = explode("/",$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);

 //print_r($url);

 if(file_exists($url[0].".php")){
  require_once($url[0].".php");
 }else{
  require_once("404.php");
 }
?>

Comment: This is the code I am using for my index page so all the pages will redirect to the index page cause I set the code on the .htaccess. When I open the about page slug it's opening. http://localhost/slug/about this is the link. But I added menu links to index.php page so it should show as main element. But it doesn't show

Comment: You need to update your question with any additional information, including your code dumps (posting unformatted code in comments is impossible to read). "But I added menu links to index.php page" - Your `.htaccess` code rewrites to `con.php`? Have you set `con.php` to be the index document. "so it should show as main element. But it doesn't show" - not sure what you mean, do you get an error? What response are you getting? This sounds like a PHP/HTML problem, not Apache/.htaccess?

Comment: OK. Let me check what is the issue 1st